# What is the equation used in R's ccf and Julia's crosscor?

Tags: r, julia, cross-correlation

I've been scratching my head a lot about this. Now, except for the fact that Julia gives out a seemingly backwards result with respect to the lags

```
julia> crosscor([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,1])'
1x7 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.30339  0.0  0.64049  0.13484  -0.37081  -0.40452  0.30339

> print(ccf(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,2,3,1), type="correlation", plot=F))

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
 0.303 -0.405 -0.371  0.135  0.640  0.000 -0.303
```

which is easily solved by inverting the x and y ("easily" is relative when it takes a hour of your life to figure out), the numbers don't resemble any of the equations I'm familiar with (which aren't many, anyway).

So, I opened up my stats textbook and found a host of other formulas which I am not going to test with pen and paper. I suspected for a moment that removing the means from the vectors played a role, so I tried not doing that (sadly, this can only be done in Julia)

```
julia> crosscor([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,1], demean=false)'
1x7 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.188562  0.518545  0.942809  0.848528  0.518545  0.235702  0.0471405
```

but this still does not resemble the normalised cross-correlation that I computed with pen and paper (pending mistakes which I may have made).

In short: I need to cite the formula, so what is it?

Comment: The R documentation `help("ccf")` contains this under "References": 
"Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002) Modern Applied Statistics with S. Fourth Edition. Springer-Verlag.
(This contains the exact definitions used.)"

Comment: Yes, I thought I'd save myself a trip to the library :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a copy of MASS handy. It's always better to look up stuff like that yourself anyway.

Comment: True that. Ah, well. My local library does not have a copy of it. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: I bet your pen & paper cross-correlation, scaled as shown in Julia's [Statsbase.jl source](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/blob/master/src/signalcorr.jl#L254) (see [`sc`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/blob/master/src/signalcorr.jl#L262)) would match.

Comment: I might need to check my maths because it doesn't, really… but then again I suppose this is why we have computers :)

Comment: I guess I expected you would calculate the equivalent of `x=[1,2,3,4];y=[1,2,3,1];crosscor(x,y,demean=false)*sqrt(dot(x,x)*dot(y,y))` which is `[4.0,11.0,20.0,18.0,11.0,5.0,1.0]`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I checked my math again and I screwed up a couple of multiplications. You'd expect that ~25 years after first learning about it, one would have mastered multiplying single digit numbers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that citing this excerpt here is ok by StackOverflow's terms of use?  From page 390 (section 14.1) of Venables and Ripley (2002) you can find the definition that they use here for the `acf()` function:

[image]

If you look at the source code of the `ccf()` function in R (type "ccf" at the prompt) you can see how `acf()` is being used and can interrogate how the above `acf()` implementation relates to the calculation.

Comment: That helps, but there are a few unclear things (like those indexes, what are they?). I suppose I'll have to grab a copy of the book.

Comment: If you're referring to `ij` they are the referring to the items of the series you're calculating correlations for at a particular lag.  These are the components that you'll see referred to in the source code for `acf()`.  I'd copy more of the explanation into the answer but don't want to infringe.  If there are specific details I can try to explain further?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I also tracked down a copy of MASS-PL e they have the same equation. I'll try to figure it out and come back here (or on Cross Validated) and ask.